# One of the many side effects of the way our brains is or are

Tags: grammar, terminology, tenses

I came across this sentence in a book I am reading but I cannot comprehend why the word 'work' is used instead of 'works' since one and way are both singular.  "This fondness for stories is just **one** of many artifacts, side effects of the **way** our brains work”

Any explanation will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: _Our brains_ is the subject of _work_ and it's plural.

Comment: If we go by grammar 'one' happens to be the subject, but that doesn't make any sense. Hence I stand by @JohnLawler

Comment: @JohnLawler How do you determine which word is the subject in the sentence? Why isn't 'the way' the subject? Thanks

Comment: If we go by grammar, _our brains_ is the subject of _work_. _One_ is not the subject of anything, since this is not a sentence. The only verb in the example is _work_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I went by the subject-line sentence that read as "One of the many side effects of the way our brains is/ are..." Here, One.... is; One of the side effects is.....; One of the many side effects is.....(.)  This has got a subject and a verb; hence it is a sentence. Yes, it is my omission that I didn't work on "This fondness for stories is just one of many artifacts, side effects of the way our brains work”.

Comment: @RamPillai I have found that the subject lines of questions do not represent the content of the question very well. It's almost as if the questioners were trying to show us how hurried and careless they were.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Fully agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

*Our brains work* is a  **reduced relative clause**. The "zero-*that*" relative clause functions as an adjective to modify *the way*:

> *the way **[that] our brains work***

I think you can now see that, in this clause, *our brains* is the plural subject of the verb *work*.